# python mock default init argument of class

Tags: python, python-unittest, magicmock

I want to mock the default argument in a class constructor:

```
class A (object):
    def __init__(self, connection=DefaultConnection()):
        self.connection = connection
```

I want to mock `DefaultConnection` in my unittests, but it doesn't work when passed in as a default value.

Comment: how to you both pass it as a default value plz? I thought that the default is there if you DON'T pass a value... also executing class initialization code during definition of another class is not very wise (`DefaultConnection()` is executed already during import of the module, not during initialization of `a = A()` if I understand it correctly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking class constructor default parameters in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704191/mocking-class-constructor-default-parameters-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use patch to [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) the module, and then you can set the return value as a Mock.

```
# --- a.py (in package path x.y) --
from c import DefaultConnection

class A (object):
    def __init__(self, connection=DefaultConnection()):
        self.connection = connection

#---- a_test.py ----
from mock import patch
from a import A

@patch('x.y.a.DefaultConnection')
def test(def_conn_mock):
  conn_mock = Mock()
  def_conn_mock.return_value = conn_mock

  a_obj = A()
  ....
```

Comment: now how do I assert that a particular function in DefaultConnection is called?

Comment: Why do you need to?

Comment: I needed to verify that this particular function is called a said number of times

Comment: If that is the case you shouldn't mock DefaultConnection but the function inside. If it is suffice to check the number of times DefaultConnection is called, you can do: def_conn_mock.call_count