# Mocking class constructor default parameters in Python

Tags: python, testing

Is there a way to mock just the default parameters of a class constructor? For example, if I have this class:

```
  class A (object):
      def __init__(self, details='example'):
          self.details = details
```

Is there a way to a mock just the default value of the `details` argument, eg to `details='test'`?

Comment: relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000970/python-mock-default-init-argument-of-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely this is simplest:

```
  class TestA (A):
      def __init__(self, details='test'):
          super(TestA, self).__init__(details)
```

If you're not able to use `TestA` without changing code elsewhere, then you could try something a bit more direct:

```
>>> A().details
'example'
>>> A.__old_init = A.__init__
>>> A.__init__ = lambda self, details='test': self.__old_init(details)
>>> A().details
'test'
```

If your willing to go that far, though, why not do it the tidy way?

```
class A (object):
    _DEFAULT_DETAILS = 'details'

    def __init__(self, details=None):
        if details is None:
            self.details = self._DEFAULT_DETAILS
        else:
            self.details = details
```

Now you can override the default value without resorting to any trickery:

```
A._DEFAULT_DETAILS = 'test'
```

Answer (score 2):

Would a new mock class do?

```
class Amock(A):
  def __init__(self, details='newdefault'):
      super(Amock, self).__init__(details=details)
```